# c++ include frameworks using code or command line options

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, static-linking

I want to compile and build a C++ program with clang compiler. (**not** **with** **XCode**).

I want to add built-in OSX frameworks into my code either using some code snippet (like #pragma comment(lib, xxx) for windows built-in libraries) or command line options.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"How can this be done?"_ Use the linker flags.

Comment: can you provide some source to learn about them?

Comment: Nope! We don't give recommendations for 3rd party resources here. Please read about [what and how you can ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). But the 1st resource should be the linker manual.

Comment: ok. thanks. I will try to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For command line option we have to use: `-framework frameworkname`